# Translate nested anonymous functions to foreach loop

Tags: c#, nested, anonymous-function, simplify

Trying to optimise some code I ended up having this kind of structure:

```
StaticMethod(propA, () => 
{
    StaticMethod(propB, () => 
    {
        StaticMethod(propC, () => 
        {
            // Write line in console here to say it's done.
        });
    });
});
```

And I was thinking there should maybe be a way to simplify that to some `foreach` or even a simple `for` loop, something like this:

```
foreach (var prop in props) // consider that `props` can be iterated over
{
    // Here I don't know how to chain everything...
}
```

Is this any doable ? Do I need to modify `StaticMethod` to achieve this ? The loop may not be enough alone, but extending the example to 1000 nested functions, I would need some iteration.

Here's the concept of `StaticMethod`:

```
static void StaticMethod(Prop prop, Action done) 
{
    // Some code here
    someDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
        // More code here
        done();
    });
}
```

Comment: Your example seems a bit too generalized; we can't even tell if your static methods act on `IEnumerable` (which is required for `foreach`)

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. You only want to process the next prop if the current one is ok? Whats the point of using the lambdas? They don't do anything in this case except make the code more confusing.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Too broad: Too many possible answers, well please point out 1 or 2 so I can see how broad it really is. Good answers too long, Servy answered in a proper format and even added more details than I asked for. This is pretty upsetting since 1. I edited the OP and 2. No edit is suggested either directly or in comments. Also it's explicit that my question can be asked with yes/no...

Comment: @Mat Servy guessed (apparently correctly); I believe I voted to close as "Unclear what you are asking", the close vote reason displayed is the majority. The question as posted put some very generic code and asked how to optimize it; without any signatures determining what the original code *did* was up to guesswork. With the added code, its far more clear.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I believe your vote was much before my substantial edit and therefore legitimate. I got 2 (I think) votes some time after my edit and so was wondering if it Still was unclear.

Comment: @Mat Its not *amazing* by any stretch but I think its pretty clear. You already have 4 reopen votes (including mine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a problem that is extremely difficult with a callback based model of asynchrony.  If you transform `StaticMethod` into a `Task` based model of asynchrony then the solution becomes *much* simpler.  If `StaticMethod` is your own method, you'd ideally just re-write it using a `Task` based model entirely, where it returns a `Task` when it has finished, rather than taking a callback, but if it's not your method, and you can't change it, you can create a wrapper that uses a `Task` based model.  To transform a callback based method into a `Task` based method you simply use a `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
public static Task StaticMethodAsync(object a)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    StaticMethod(a, () => tcs.SetResult(true));
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Now that we have that we can write an `async` method that iterates over `props` and calls each asynchronous method in turn:

```
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    await StaticMethodAsync(prop);
}
// Write line in console here to say it's done.
```

If you *really* want to solve this problem while maintaining a callback model, you *can*, but, as you can see below, it's much harder to read, understand, and step through:

```
public static void Foo(object[] props, Action callback)
{
    int i = -1;
    Action innerCallback = null;
    innerCallback = () =>
    {
        i++;
        if (i < props.Length)
        {
            StaticMethod(props[i], innerCallback);
        }
        else
        {
            callback();
        }
    };
    innerCallback();
}
```

Comment: I don't see any asynchronous processing in the question... To me it looks like some awkward builder pattern... But you could be right.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The delegate doesn't return anything, so it's an `Action`.  If it were using it to compute a value, then sure.  But since it's an action, this transformation would be valid, even if it does happen to call the delegate before it returns.  And the comment `// Write line in console here to say it's done.` makes a pretty compelling case for the delegate being a callback that indicates the completion of a process.

Comment: @Servy At first glance that looks promising. Please see my edit since I reckon I should've included that code when I posted. Will try to implement your solution with `Task` !

Comment: @Mat The edit shows pretty much exactly the code I expected it to have been when I wrote the answer.  If it's your method, you should really re-write it to just use a `Task` based model entirely, rather than having it take a callback and then having a wrapper that returns a `Task`.

Comment: @Servy I'm asking you since you have clearly understood my question; was the Too Broad flag used correctly here ? I may put it up on Meta if I get absolutely no help from the voters.

Comment: @Mat The quesiton is most certainly not Too Broad.  I could understand an indication to vote to close before the edits (which was when most of the votes were cast) but not anymore.

Comment: What should I do then ? Also, concerning your answer, I get the exception `Task does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'` on the line `await StaticMethodAsync(prop);`. I looked it up but can't quite tell what's the problem since I'm not used to using Task.

Comment: @Mat I've you've never used it before then you're going to want to start with some intro tutorials on the subject; explaining all of the basics is beyond the scope of what can be discussed in an SO post.  That *is* very much Too Broad.

Comment: Right, I will keep reading about it. Since I implemented your solution directly I though it might be useful for you to know I get that exception. Might be my context though so I'll get to work. Thanks.

Comment: @Servy Your callback model (which I don't personally find "hard to understand") worked like a charm. I have accepted your post as answer. Hopefully I find out why I couldn't get Task to work properly.

Comment: @Mat You should absolutely not use that approach.  It's going to be *much* harder to work with, particularly the instant you try to do all but the most trivial of operations.  Being able to just write `foreach(var item in sequence) await someMethod(item);` is *dramatically* better.  Be considerate of your future self and take the time to learn the basics of the Task model.

Comment: @Servy as much as I agree with you, I'm on strict deadlines right now and unless I figure out the error I told you I get, I need a quick solution asap. Your edit does just that.